# How can I troubleshoot a black screen appearing after my React website loads?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, npm

[Error messages can be seen in photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO6gy.png)there is no error in my terminal my website is fully able to load. However when I opened my dev tools.I was able to load my site and then i tried making some styling changes. I reverted my site back not saving any styling changes. Then I was not able to see my site. It loads and then a black screen appears. I see the following error messages:

```
The above error occurred in the <div> component:

    at div

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.

react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Canvas)> component:

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367

react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught Error: R3F: Div is not part of the THREE namespace! Did you forget to extend? See: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/objects#using-3rd-party-objects-declaratively
```

I tried deleting my node modules and pack.lock json files and running npm i and npm install. That did not solve the problem. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Don't make us guess at your code.

Answer (score 1):

Delete

fallback={} in computers.jsx file.

then run npm run dev
its a syntax error causing all the other errors in the dev tools